# How would i even call setPrice at all?

Tags: java, methods

```
package order;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Order {

    /*int fries = 5;
    int burger = 7;
    int soda = 4;
    int coffee = 3;
    int donut = 6;
    */
    double price;

    public static void printMenu(String[][] menu) {
        for(int rows = 0; rows < menu.length;rows++) {
            for(int columns = 0; columns < menu[rows].length;columns++) {
                System.out.println(menu[rows][columns]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void choose(double price) {
        this.price = price;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuNumber = sc.nextInt();

        switch(menuNumber) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You added fries");
                price = price + 5.00;
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("You added a burger");
                price = price +7.00;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("You added a soda");
                price = price + 4.00;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("You added coffee");
                price = price + 3.00;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("You added donut");
                price = price + 6.00;
            default:
                System.out.println("You need to choose an order 1-5");

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] menu = {{"fries : $5.00","burger: $7.00","soda: $4.00","coffee: $3.00","donut: $6.00"}};
        printMenu(menu);
        choose(price);

    }
}
```

I am confused how to even call the setPrice method at all? I am trying to call it through the main method, but it gives me an error:(Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field 
 price). What do I need to do to call the setPrice method?

Comment: Instantiate a new object of type `Order`, then call `setPrice(...)` on the new object.

Comment: Or Google this site on: [java how to call a non static method from main](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+how+to+call+a+non+static+method+from+main+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please check my link above as it provides a good way to search for common questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Because `main` is a `static` method (i.e., it belongs to the class as a whole, and not any particular instance of a class), you must create an `Order` object in order to access or set the instance variable `price` from the `main` method.

I would initialize `price` to `0.0` in an `Order` constructor, since that will always be the starting value.

Then, in `main`, initialize an `Order` object and invoke `choose` to start adding items. There's no need to pass the price to the `choose` method because it is an instance variable of the `order` object just created.

```
Order order = new Order();
order.choose();
```

The reason this works is because we've now created an `Order` instance, allowing us to invoke non-static methods (i.e., methods that belongs to a particular `class`). You can also now invoke `setPrice` directly with `order`.